# set FlyoutLayoutBehavior to FlyoutLayoutBehavior.SplitOnLandscape on Shell page

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms, maui, maui-windows

I am trying to create a desktop application using .net MAUI. I am planning to `Shell` class for my main page.
When I am trying to add flyout behavior to `FlyoutLayoutBehavior.SplitOnLandscape`, I cannot find any setting for that in `Shell` class.

I can find those setting if i replace `Shell` class with `FlyoutPage` class

Answer (score 1):

There is a known issue about this problem.

You can follow it up here: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/7161 .

Thanks for your support and feedback.

Best Regards.

Comment: Hi @Firdaus Kamaruddin, if my reply is useful for this problem, could you please mark it as answered so that  it will help others who have similar problems? Thanks in advance. :)